# Subquery com os registros de uma coluna

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper, dql

Tenho o seguinte problema... Preciso extrair as informações de uma tabela onde possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
tabela: PROCESSO_VALOR_TIPO  
Coluna : field_model_ids  
Dados : 135;137;138;139;140;878;879;880;881;882
```

<sup>OBS: PRECISO UTILIZAR ESSES DADOS COMO SUBCONSULTA</sup>

**Minha query :**

```
SELECT *
  FROM FIELD_MODEL
 where FIELD_MODEL_ID IN
       (SELECT REPLACE(FIELD_MODEL_IDS, ';', ',')
          FROM PROCESSO_VALOR_TIPO
         where processo_valor_tipo_id = 1176);
```

**ERRO:**

> ORA-01722: número inválido
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Qual seria a melhor forma pra retornar esses dados? Já tentei de diversas formas e nenhuma com êxito

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi... vc tem uma tabela chamada PROCESSO_VALOR_TIPO com um campo chamado field_model_ids e se vc fizer um select dela, vai trazer 135, 137, 138, etc, é isso? Ou o campo é um 'linguição' todo juntando todos esses IDs?

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo `processo_valor_tipo_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a consulta abaixo você vai conseguir transformar sua lista de string em linhas, com ela você poderá usar dentro do seu subselect

```
SELECT trim(regexp_substr(FIELD_MODEL_IDS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
FROM PROCESSO_VALOR_TIPO
CONNECT BY instr(FIELD_MODEL_IDS, ';', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
```

Sua consulta final ficaria assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM FIELD_MODEL
WHERE FIELD_MODEL_ID IN (    
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr(FIELD_MODEL_IDS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
    FROM PROCESSO_VALOR_TIPO
    CONNECT BY instr(FIELD_MODEL_IDS, ';', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0)
```